# Passing an array to a method in controller from a js file and getting back the value

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, string, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass value from js to a method gateway in Home controller and I want the result back(Integer)

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/gateway?s=' + dates[],
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: 'value' },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please let us know at least, what is the structure response from backend or so.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing url query parameters in a POST request which by design should expect a payload body. Why not add another property called dates inside of your data object and set its value to the `dates` array?

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/gateway',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    id: 'value',
    dates
  },
  success: () => {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: () => {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```